# Python Error code: 'List has no attribute 'txt'

Tags: python

I am trying to call a function- write_corpus_to_file, however when I run the program I get the error code 'Attribute error: List has no attribute 'txt''. I am a python beginner, can anyone help?

THE FUNCTION:

```
def write_corpus_to_file(mycorpus, myfile):
    f = open(myfile, 'w')
    newcorpus = ''.join(mycorpus)
    f.write(newcorpus)
    f.close()
```

SECTION OF THE MAIN LOOP:

```
elif user_input=="a":
    addseq = input("Enter new input to corpus ")
    tidy_text(addseq)
    extcorpus = corpus.extend(addseq)
    write_corpus_to_file(extcorpus, corpus.txt)
```

Comment: `myfile` should be a string, not a variable name. So `corpus.txt` should really be `"corpus.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put the filename in quotes:

```
write_corpus_to_file(extcorpus, "corpus.txt")
```

If you don't have quotes, then python takes `corpus.txt` literally, and attempts to access the `txt` attribute of the variable called `corpus`. That of course doesn't exist, hence the error.

Also, a recommendation. Instead of this:

```
f = open(myfile, 'w')
f.write(newcorpus)
f.close()
```

Do this:

```
with open(myfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(newcorpus)
```

This method ensures that resources are properly released, and that the file is written to and closed properly even in case of an error.

**EDIT**: `extend`, like other functions that operate on lists, works *in-place*. This means that it modifies the list, and does not return a new one. Therefore when you do `extcorpus = corpus.extend(addseq)`, `extcorpus` is given no value, since `extend` doesn't return anything.

Change your code like so:

```
elif user_input=="a":
    addseq = input("Enter new input to corpus ")
    tidy_text(addseq)
    corpus.extend(addseq)
    write_corpus_to_file(corpus, "corpus.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you! When I do this however I am getting another error code: TypeError: Can only join an iterable